# How to render certain records when a button is pressed (LWC)

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have a LWC which renders some customer's invoices by clicking the search button:

[image]

But i need when the user presses the next button to render other records and not those appearing when the search button is pressed.

My Html code:

```
<div class="slds-m-around_medium">

<template if:true={pressedButton}>
    <template if:true={invoiceList}>
        <h1>{label.invoice}</h1>
        <div class="row"> </div> 
    <lightning-datatable data={invoiceList} selected-rows={selectedRows} columns={columns} key-field="Id"  max-row-selection=1 onrowaction={handleRowAction} onrowselection={handleRowSelection} min-column-width=200>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

My js:

```
export default class El_getCustomerInvoices extends LightningElement {

@track pressedButton=false;
@track pressedNextButton=false;
@track selectInvoiceRecord=false;

@track error;
@track invoiceList ;
@api recordId;
@api subscriptionfield=false;
@api fromDT;
@api toDT;
@api pagePos = 0; //added by :christos

columns = columns;

    //Call APex to get the invoicesList
    //Call method and add the parameters                                                                                                      
    @wire(getInvoices,{customerId: '$recordId', fromDate: '$fromDT', toDate: '$toDT',meterNum: '$selectedmeter',subscriptionNUm: '$selectedname', pagePosition: '$pagePos'})  //2019-10-09
    wiredInvoices({ error, data }) 
    {
        if (data) {
            this.pressedButton = false;
            this.pressedNextButton = false;
            this.selectInvoiceRecord = false;
            //Ebg: pass the returmed list from apex to invoice list in order to be displayed in the invoices data table
            this.invoiceList = data;
            console.log('The Data returned by APEX: ' +JSON.stringify(data));
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.invoiceList = undefined;
        }
    }


//search button pressed
searchClicked() {
    if(this.pressedButton == false){    
        this.pressedButton = true;
    } 
}
nextClicked(){
    if(this.pressedNextButton == false){    
        this.pressedNextButton = true;
        this.pagePos = 6;
        console.log('Next pagePos ' +this.pagePos);
    }
}
```

My Apex Class:

```
@auraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<el_invoices> getInvoices(id customerId, String fromDate, String toDate, String meterNum, String subscriptionNUm, Integer pagePosition){
    List<el_invoices> results = new List<el_invoices>();
    try{
        system.debug('fromDate apex'+fromDate);
        system.debug('ToDate apex'+toDate);
        system.debug('meterNum apex'+meterNum);
        system.debug('subscriptionNUm apex'+subscriptionNUm);
        system.debug('PagePosition apex '+pagePosition);
        //Part of processing input date
        String[] fromStrDate = fromDate.split('-');
        Integer fromIntDate = integer.valueOf(fromStrDate[2]);
        Integer fromIntMonth = integer.valueOf(fromStrDate[1]);
        Integer fromIntYear = integer.valueOf(fromStrDate[0]);
        Date fDate = Date.newInstance(fromIntYear, fromIntMonth, fromIntDate);
        
        //Part of processing input date
        String[] toStrDate = fromDate.split('-');
        Integer toIntDate = integer.valueOf(toStrDate[2]);
        Integer toIntMonth = integer.valueOf(toStrDate[1]);
        Integer toIntYear = integer.valueOf(toStrDate[0]);
        Date tDate = Date.newInstance(toIntYear, toIntMonth, toIntDate);


        /*results.add('0000000001'); //invoice #
        results.add('09-2020,10-2020'); //Invoice Period
        results.add('Clearing Bill'); //Invoice Type
        results.add('100'); //Invoice Total Amount
        results.add('Related Services'); //Invoices Related Services (?)
        results.add('01-09-2020'); //Invoice Date
        results.add('01-10-2020'); //Invoice Due Date
        results.add('0'); //Invoice Pending Amount
        results.add('01-10-2020'); //Final Settlement Date
        results.add('123456789'); //Meter Number
        results.add('987654321'); //Subscription Number

        return results;*/


        el_PageSize__c ps = [select Page_Size__c from el_PageSize__c];
        Decimal dValue = ps.Page_Size__c;
        Integer pageSizeNum = dValue.intValue();
        csord__Subscription__c subSupply = [select id, el_SupplyNumber__c, el_Supply_Type__c from csord__Subscription__c where csordtelcoa__Subscription_Number__c=: subscriptionNUm];
        //Ebg: Until the real call construct a dummy record
        
        for (Integer i=1; i<= pageSizeNum; i++) {
            system.debug('Page Pos before if and inside for '+pagePosition );
            if(pagePosition == 0){ 
                system.debug('Page Pos after if and inside for '+pagePosition );
            el_invoices dummyRecord = new el_invoices();
            dummyRecord.InvoiceNumber='0000000001';//+string.valueOf(i);
            dummyRecord.InvoicePeriod='09-2020,10-2020';
            dummyRecord.InvoiceType='Clearing Bill';
            dummyRecord.InvoiceTotalAmount=100.00;
            dummyRecord.RelatedServices='Related Services';
            dummyRecord.InvoiceDate=Date.valueOf('2019-10-08');
            dummyRecord.InvoiceDueDate=Date.valueOf('2019-10-09');
            dummyRecord.InvInvoicePendingAmount=0;
            dummyRecord.FinalSettlementDate=Date.valueOf('2020-10-01');
            dummyRecord.MeterNumber=meterNum;
            dummyRecord.SubscriptionNumber=subscriptionNUm;
            //added
            dummyRecord.InvoiceId = '0000000001'; //+string.valueOf(i);
            dummyRecord.AccountId = '0000000001';//+string.valueOf(i);
            if(subSupply.el_Supply_Type__c == 'Electricity'){
            dummyRecord.ElSupplyId = subSupply.el_SupplyNumber__c;
            }else if(subSupply.el_Supply_Type__c == 'Natural Gas'){
            dummyRecord.NGSupplyId = subSupply.el_SupplyNumber__c;
            }
            dummyRecord.BillNo = '0000000001'; //+string.valueOf(i);
            dummyRecord.IssueDate = system.today();
            dummyRecord.DueDate = system.today() + 5;
            dummyRecord.InvoiceFlow = 'Test data';
            dummyRecord.Credited = 10.0;
            dummyRecord.BillFrom = 'Test Account';
            dummyRecord.BillTo = 'Test Account';
            dummyRecord.EnergyDayKWh = 12.0;
            dummyRecord.EnergyNightKWh = 15.0;
            dummyRecord.ConsumptionNM3 = 100.0;
            dummyRecord.PreviousUnpaid = 5151.0;
            dummyRecord.GrandTotal = 54121.0;
            //transactionInfo--> one callOut will be performed
            dummyRecord.TransactionChargeType='Monthly Bill';//+string.valueOf(i);
            dummyRecord.TransactionChargeAmount=73.79;
            //balanceInfo --> one callout will be performed
            dummyRecord.RemainingAmount=8.8;//+i;
            dummyRecord.RunningBalance=0;
            dummyRecord.OutstandingBalance=0;
            results.add(dummyRecord);
            }
            if(pagePosition == 6){
                el_invoices dummyRecord1 = new el_invoices();
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceNumber='0000000002';//+string.valueOf(i);
                dummyRecord1.InvoicePeriod='09-2020,10-2020';
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceType='Clearing Bill';
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceTotalAmount=100.00;
                dummyRecord1.RelatedServices='Related Services';
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceDate=Date.valueOf('2019-10-08');
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceDueDate=Date.valueOf('2019-10-09');
                dummyRecord1.InvInvoicePendingAmount=0;
                dummyRecord1.FinalSettlementDate=Date.valueOf('2020-10-01');
                dummyRecord1.MeterNumber=meterNum;
                dummyRecord1.SubscriptionNumber=subscriptionNUm;
                //added
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceId = '0000000001'; //+string.valueOf(i);
                dummyRecord1.AccountId = '0000000001';//+string.valueOf(i);
                if(subSupply.el_Supply_Type__c == 'Electricity'){
                    dummyRecord1.ElSupplyId = subSupply.el_SupplyNumber__c;
                }else if(subSupply.el_Supply_Type__c == 'Natural Gas'){
                    dummyRecord1.NGSupplyId = subSupply.el_SupplyNumber__c;
                }
                dummyRecord1.BillNo = '0000000001'; //+string.valueOf(i);
                dummyRecord1.IssueDate = system.today();
                dummyRecord1.DueDate = system.today() + 5;
                dummyRecord1.InvoiceFlow = 'Test data';
                dummyRecord1.Credited = 10.0;
                dummyRecord1.BillFrom = 'Test Account';
                dummyRecord1.BillTo = 'Test Account';
                dummyRecord1.EnergyDayKWh = 12.0;
                dummyRecord1.EnergyNightKWh = 15.0;
                dummyRecord1.ConsumptionNM3 = 100.0;
                dummyRecord1.PreviousUnpaid = 5151.0;
                dummyRecord1.GrandTotal = 54121.0;
                //transactionInfo--> one callOut will be performed
                dummyRecord1.TransactionChargeType='Monthly Bill';//+string.valueOf(i);
                dummyRecord1.TransactionChargeAmount=73.79;
                //balanceInfo --> one callout will be performed
                dummyRecord1.RemainingAmount=8.8;//+i;
                dummyRecord1.RunningBalance=0;
                dummyRecord1.OutstandingBalance=0;
                results.add(dummyRecord1);  
            }
        }
            return results;
    }catch(AuraHandledException e){
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        //system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I also have an apex in which i return certain records based on the pagePos variable. What i need is to when i press the search button to render certain records based on the criteria in apex and when the next is pressed render some other records (based on apex criteria). I tried to use or in html :  but it doesn't compile. Any thoughts about how could i do this?
Currently, when i click search button it renders the right records, when i press the next button it vanishes the table and if i click again the search the right records are rendered.

Thank you.

Comment: So like pagination? when you search, show first n records, then when you hit next, the next n records?

Comment: Exactly. Currently in my apex i have some dummy records with two if. The first runs when the pagePos is 0 and the other when the pagePos is 6.

Comment: You could use LIMIT and OFFSET in your SOQL. Use Database.query(query) so you can make it dynamic and use the value of pagePos to affect the offset value. So if you wanted to have 5 records per page and you're on page two 'SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 5 offset 5'

Comment: Also, you may not want to use a wire adapter here. It may make more sense to just call the Apex method when you click search/next. Since you know for sure you don't need to query it until Search is clicked.

Comment: The number of records appearing each time are based on a custom setting where the user just sets a number. I will update my initial question with my apex code so it may help you out.

Comment: So pagination where they can change how many results per page?

Comment: Yes, this custom setting indicates how many results will be previewed per page.

Comment: So LIMIT = pageSizeNum and OFFSET = pageSizeNum*pagePosition But it looks like you should rework the way pagePos works in the JavaScript so it just increments a value instead of setting it to 6. Which means you may need to do pagePosition+1 in the apex if you start from 0

Comment: I commented out the pressedButton and the pressedNextButton under the @wire and the problem was solved. Thank you for your time!